# pyexcel - is there a way to get the column width?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pyexcel

I have an excel sheet that I can display via `pyexcel.get_book` like this:

```
    +------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
    | Rec No.                | Title | Forenames     | Surname      | Address                                                         | Plaintiff Name         | Amount   |
    +------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
    | 01                     | MR    | GUY PERSON    | FITZGERALD   | 69 BLAZEIT TERRACE, BAGEL ROAD, ST SAVIOUR, GERBILTONG, JE2 7TR | BANANA COMPANY LIMITED | 69420.69 |
    +------------------------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
```

Is there a way to determine the width of the column that pyexcel calculates to display the table above (address is longer than the rest for example)? Like a `col.width`?

I want to convert this table to an image that takes up the full width of a page. The columns are of different widths, which I would like to use.